# value being changed in codeigniter model function

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

This my function

```
public function update_previous_fee($id, $date, $amount) {

        $month = date("F, Y", strtotime($date));
        $this->db->where('mwf_month', $month);
        $this->db->where('mwf_student_id', $id);
        $this->db->set('mwf_pay_day', $date, FALSE);
        $this->db->set('mwf_payment', $amount, FALSE);
        $this->db->update('mwf');
}
```

the mwf_pay_day is being set to some garbage negative value. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Before you insert the values, try and dump them, so you can make sure everything is as it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

changing the line

```
$this->db->set('mwf_pay_day', $date, FALSE);
```

to

```
$this->db->set('mwf_pay_day', $date, TRUE);
```

solves the problem.

See [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) `$this->db->set();` for details

Answer (score 0):

```
 $dt=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)); //converting the format as per the database format.
 $month = date("F, Y", strtotime($date));
 $this->db->where('mwf_month', $month);
 $this->db->where('mwf_student_id', $id);
 $this->db->set('mwf_pay_day', $dt, FALSE);
 $this->db->set('mwf_payment', $amount, FALSE);
 $this->db->update('mwf');
```

Hope now it will work for you.

Comment: It doesn't change anything

Comment: Can you please check the Data Type of "mwf_pay_day" field in the table.

Comment: data type is string. I am passing a string $date to db. but when i create $month. how does it affect $date.

Comment: okay.I will try that. Actual question was here that why a string($date) [i am reading it from a csv] is not being inserted to   a field which is also varchar type.

Comment: It will also store the string into your field but the standard is to store the date formatted data. And it will help you in future to calculate anything you need for this dates.

Comment: i dumped the $dt value and it shows the value i intend to pass. but it is string(10) "2014-09-09". if $dt is string why i changed the db field type to date. and it doesn't work for either.

Comment: Actually it is not string but it will show as string. if you gone through the database data types you will get all the details.